# Spanning one Typescript module across files gives 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: typescript

I'm having issues when spanning a module across multiple files. I know there are a lot of questions on stackoverflow, but they are not sufficient to this issue.

The two relevant portion of the two files:

file _ProjectInfo.ts:

```
/// <reference path="_ProjectInfo2.ts" />

module Areas.ProjectArea._ProjectInfo
{
    window.onload = ()=> {
        var EventHandlers: ButtonEventHandlers = new ButtonEventHandlers();
        ....
    };
}
```

The _ProjectInfo2.ts file:

```
module Areas.ProjectArea._ProjectInfo
{
    export class ButtonEventHandlers
    {       
        public EditProjectButtonClickEventHandler(): void {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

When these modules are in separte files I get the error:

**0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action**

It breaks on:

```
var EventHandlers: ButtonEventHandlers = new ButtonEventHandlers();
```

When I put the code in one file, everything works correctly as expected. I think I have the correct references put in my files, but I cannot get it working in separate files.

Comment: Do you have script tags that load both .js files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to ensure `_ProjectInfo2.ts` is loaded before `_ProjectInfo.ts` as you need the class defined before you use it

Comment: Thanks Basarat, not only needed I to reference the file, but also load in the CSHTML page (seems logic to me, but I didn't realize that)

Comment: I've blogged about common issues with typescript: http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/12/24/common-errors-issues-typescript-visual-studio/