# Typescript over Multiple Files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

So I'm a C++ programmer who made some stuff in Dart and is now transitioning to Typescript. I'm tackling one issue at a time and now the single file full of classes is beginning to get to me. When trying to find info on the matter I'm dumbstruck that there are so many methods of including files and that each method is very verbose. In fact this whole topic is still bleeding edge and under active development.

So I'm not using any External libraries so Internal Modules will do. However, when I try to initialize a global variable who's class is defined in another typescript file under the same module name I get the following error:

0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

When looking on StackOverflow I can find the exact same scenario:
[Spanning one Typescript module across files gives 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641352/spanning-one-typescript-module-across-files-gives-0x800a01bd-javascript-runtim)

However am I led to believe that I'm supposed to be feeding each .js file into the html in such an order so that everything can be resolved ? Surely this cannot be correct, why can't visual studio resolve the order for me and spit out a single .js file ?

I've tried Setting up the Typescript build to combine into a single .js file, and referring to that one in my html. That actually worked once and failed every time after that. (cacheing ?) Obviously I must be missing something, So I'd like to ask for your help.

In Dart this was very straightforward, yet in typescript this is very confusing and cumbersome. AMD, UMD, tsconfig.json, etc... As a C++ guy, I like Namespaces and include directives, above all they are simple and just work while providing all the functionality you need.

So what is the most relevant, up to date manner of handling this and what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

So as suspected when using multiple files you have to feed them into your HTML in an order that everything will resolve. (Please don't...)

When Combining JavaScript Output into one file make sure that ECMAScript 5 is selected, NOT ECMAScript 6, as that one will crash and burn.

Also delete that combined Javascript file to be sure, so a fresh one is generated. You may also want to do some cleanup as VS2015 will not delete any .js & .js.map files for you, so your directory will likely be littered with useless files.

**/Update**

You need to delete the generated combined Javascript file each time you build, as it won't otherwise update...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Visual Studio 2015, but I will describe a straightforward way to setup a namespaced, single file TypeScript project that will be compiled using `tsc`.

Create a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project which contains:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "out": "SomeNamespace.js"
    }
}
```

That will tell the TypeScript compiler to compile everything in the directory with a `.ts` extension into a single file named `SomeNamespace.js`.

Create an example file named `Foo.ts` which contains:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    export class Foo {}
}
```

Notice, I used `namespace` instead of `module`. Internal modules are now called namespaces and the `namespace` keyword can be used.

> Going forward, internal modules will be called ‘namespace’.  We chose to use this term because of the closeness between how this form works and namespaces in other languages [...]
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5.aspx

Create another example file named `Bar.ts` which contains:

```
/// <reference path="Foo.ts"/>

namespace SomeNamespace {
    export class Bar {}
}
```

This one contains a reference to `Foo.ts`. This ensures that the code contained in `Foo.ts` is included before `Bar.ts` during compilation.

Lastly, run `tsc` in the project's directory where the `tsconfig.json` file is located, and everything will be compiled into `SomeNamespace.js`.

As a side note, you can run `tsc --watch` for the compiler to compile on save.